# How to use a flatpickr with a vue component?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component

Disclaimer: I'm new to vue.js

Im need help to get a date picker working with my modal components. I have made the modal and that workers fine, I've also installed a date picker ('flatpickr') and that works fine when I call it on an element not within a component.

However when I try to use it on the modal nothing happens. Im unsure where I should be calling the date picker within the component as I thought you should refrain from putting anything with side effects as they won't me parsed.

Im unsure where is should be including the flatpickr script, should it be within the template or should it be in my main app.js.

My modal component.vue

```
<template>
<div class="cis-modal is-active">
 <div class="cis-modal-background">
    <div class="cis-modal-content animated bounceInUp">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">

                <slot></slot>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="cis-modal-close" @click="$emit('closed')"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
</div>
</div>

<script>
 export default {
 }
</script>
```

The flatpickr script

```
<script>
 $("#talentDOB").flatpickr({
 enableTime: true,
 dateFormat: "F, d Y H:i"
});
```

The modal being called

```
<modal v-if="showEditTalentModal" @closed="showEditTalentModal = false;">
{!! Form::model($talent, ['method' => 'PATCH', 'action' =>     ['TalentController@update', $talent->user_id], 'files'=>true ]) !!}

<div class="form-group">
  {!! Form::label('dob', 'Date of Birth:') !!}
  {!! Form::text('dob', null, [ 'data-input','class'=>'form-control',  'required' => 'required', 'id' => 'talentDOB']) !!}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
 {!! Form::submit('Update Profile', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary']) !!}
</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
</modal>
```

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, import the component.

```
import flatpickr from 'flatpickr'
```

Then create the flatpicker instance in mounted

```
flatpickr('#datepicker')
```

Of course you need to have an input with the same id

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" v-model="dateValue" autocomplete="off"/>
```

Actually there is no any special requirements yo use it in Vue.

Comment: I also had to load css manually to make it work    
`require("flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.css")`